# Use custom function within view/controller/etc

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter, so this may sound a bit stupid.

But here's what I want :

- Have my own classes, with functions, etc
- Be able to use them either in a view or a controller

(I've thought of simply `require_once`ing the necessary files, or perhaps creating a CI `Library`, but I'm still not sure)

What's the most CI-friendly and efficient way you would suggest? Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html):

```
$this->load->library('my_class');
$this->my_class->some_function();
```

EDIT:

It is not recommended, but if you must use the library in the view, use it like this:

```
$data['my_class'] =& $this->my_class;
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

Comment: Well, that's what I was thinking too... Thanks (again)!

Comment: One question though : Let's say I set up a library, and autoload it. How could I use it from my view??

Comment: You shouldn't do it from inside the view. Do as much work as possible in the model/controller. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622745/codeigniter-loading-a-library-from-a-view

Comment: Hmmm... I get your point, but what I want to do is basically group a few repetitive html-producing functions (like "echo 3 input fields"), which is too view-oriented (wouldn't that... "violate" the MVC logic, if I stuff that in a controller?). An idea : would creating a "Helper" sound more sensible?

Comment: A helper function sounds reasonable. This code is not class specific, thus there is no need to send an entire class object to the view.