# Session lost from php page to codeignighter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, post

I have a button that POST data to my site

```
<form action="https://www.mysite.co.uk/some/index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="ZUpmenVaN0ZVTTBmejNGZGNwZGFha1NmR0tuSjdaT3VYdjV5cTF4WGtISzRvK0ptOC9vZmQyc3J3T3cwTmplbWZ3alhod0xMYUhlQ2xLSng4WWI4ZEE9PQ2">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" style="font-size:14px; padding:20px;">
</form>
```

I then turn it into usable session

**mysite.co.uk/some/index.php**

```
<?php session_start();
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['userid'])) {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $_POST['userid'];
        $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        echo "You are logged in and have access to these tests.";?>
code here
  <?php
    } else {
        header ('location: ../index.htm');
    }
    ?>
```

this all works well.

I now want to use this within a countersign project with the same website (this is where it goes wrong)

**mysite.co.uk/some/tests/ETray/New/**

```
 <?php
  $this->load->library('session');
  $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $_POST['userid']);
  $userID = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
  echo "$userID";
  ?>
```

I get error

> Message: Undefined index: userid

unless I post direct to this page like

```
<form action="https://www.mysite.co.uk/some/tests/ETray/New/" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="ZUpmenVaN0ZVTTBmejNGZGNwZGFha1NmR0tuSjdaT3VYdjV5cTF4WGtISzRvK0ptOC9vZmQyc3J3T3cwTmplbWZ3alhod0xMYUhlQ2xLSng4WWI4ZEE9PQ2">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" style="font-size:14px; padding:20px;">
</form>
```

Then no error and the echo prints out.

**Question**

how do I get this to echo out on this page with the first form not the second ?

Comment: Where is that session load taking place?  The controller or the view?

Comment: view atm for testing

Comment: You have to load the library in the view different than you do in the controller.  [Try this to load differently in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622745/codeigniter-loading-a-library-from-a-view), but check the answer with the highest score rather than the accepted answer.  See if that helps your cause.

Comment: I have session auto loaded though ?

Comment: Ahhh...if the session is autoloaded, remove that load in the view entirely.  I'll submit an answer now, though.

Comment: Thanks, have tries. but still cant get the session, I seem to loose it from some/index.php to  some/tests/ETray/New/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that error `Message: Undefined index: userid`is due to the undefined index of `$_POST['userid']`

Another one, where does `mysite.co.uk/some/tests/ETray/New/` points to?? Is that inside controller or where???