# How to call own library in view page

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries

My library name is numbertowords and it's in library folder and i want to call it in view page..How do i call?? i called like this

```
<?php
$this->load->library('numbertowords');
?>
<?php 
echo $this->numbertowords->convert_number($row['billtotal']); 
echo" Rupees Only"
?>
</h3>
```

I am getting error like this

A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice

```
Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$numbertowords

Filename: Inventory/Bill_Print1.php

Line Number: 233

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva3\application\views\Inventory\Bill_Print1.php
Line: 233
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva3\application\controllers\TipUp_Loan.php
Line: 74
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva3\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once


Fatal error: Call to a member function convert_number() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Yuva3\application\views\Inventory\Bill_Print1.php on line 233
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function convert_number() on null

Filename: Inventory/Bill_Print1.php

Line Number: 233

Backtrace:
```

Comment: it is not a good practice to call library in view, you should call the library in your controller and pass the converted number to view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter - loading a library from a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622745/codeigniter-loading-a-library-from-a-view)

Comment: okey..how do i call the function in view page..??

Comment: Include a copy of your library

Comment: didn't understand@Alex

Answer (score 0):

changed my library file name from numbertowords To Numbertowords..

```
    <?php
$this->load->library('Numbertowords');
?>
<?php 
echo $this->numbertowords->convert_number($row['billtotal']); 
echo" Rupees Only"
?>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$this` is not what you think it is.

What you're expecting it to be is a reference to the controller instance (sometimes called the "CI Super object"), but it is actually an instance of the loader (`$this->load`).

The library should be loaded in the controller and `convert_number()` used to modify data there before it is passed to the view.